# Select content within a variable instead of within the current DOM with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an ajax function using jQuery that defines an error function to be called. When an error occurs on the server this error function runs. One of the variables passed in "jqXHR" contains a property called responseText. I want to dump this response text into a div on the page, but the response text contains a fully-formed HTML document. Is there any way to use jQuery to traverse this variable containing HTML in the same way I would traverse the regular DOM?

```
$.ajax({
    blah blah blah...,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        var errorText = $(jqXHR.responseText).find('body').html();
        // The above line does not work. errorText is NULL.
        $('#mainContent').html(errorText);
    }
});
```

I would like to do something like the above code snippet but the way I'm doing it does not work. Is there a way to traverse this variable as if it were a DOM that I could navigate with jQuery?

### UPDATE

Here is a `console.log($(jqXHR.responseText))`

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/consolelog.jpg

Comment: Can you do a `console.log($(jqXHR.responseText));` and see what the dom looks like to be sure ... i know that jQuery often selects the `body` by default so it may be you dont need to use the extra `$()` and jsut need to do `errorText = $(jqXHR.responseText).html();` OR `errorText = $('#mainContent', jqXHR.responseText).html();` Also your response is comign over with `text/html` and not an xml content type, right?

Comment: Yes the response is text/html. For some reason this only works if I don't use `.html()`, but then I also get the contents of the HEAD tag in addition to the contents of the BODY tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sweet discovery for me as well on this one.

This doesn't work because behind the scenes, jQuery is creating a document fragment and setting the innerHtml property on it.  This *does not work* with the `<html>` and `<body>` nodes because those aren't document node types--they cannot be placed into the DOM.

Instead, when you call `$('<html><body><b>foo</b></body></html>')`, a fragment is created with just "`<b>foo</b>`" in it!  So, you want just the body part?  Just return:

```
$(jqXHR.responseText).html();
```

Fiddle to prove what I'm referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/L5PR5/1/

---

**EDIT #2**

I think your only choice, given that `<head>` elements are being put in there, is to use substrings:

```
var res = jqXHR.responseText;
$(res.substring(res.indexOf('<body'))).appendTo('#mainContent');
```

Comment: You are correct but for some reason it only works if I leave off the `.html()`. When I just do `$('#mainContent').html($(jqXHR.responseText))` I get the contents of the HEAD section and the BODY section injected into the page. How do I get just the body section? `.html()` leaves errorText null again.

Comment: You're forgetting the difference between `$('#mainContent ').html('text')` and `$('text').html()`.  What you did was set the innerHtml property of your #mainContent to the string that you set.  What I did was construct a new node with that HTML in it.  I recommend this:  `$(jqXHR.responseText).appendTo('#mainContent');`  I bet that'll work.

Comment: `$('#mainContent').append(jqXHR.responseText)` gives me the same result. I have the content of the HEAD tag as well as the BODY tag. I just want the content of the BODY from jqXHR.responseText, but not the content of the HEAD tag.

Please see my update for a `console.log($(jqXHR.responseText))`

Comment: Interesting indeed!  See my edit--use substring.  I think it's your only choice.

Comment: I am sad that substring is the only option, but hey, it works :)

Comment: @Alex, posted an alternative (*if the html is valid xml*)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var errorText = $('<div />').append(jqXHR.responseText).html();
```

and here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7Sfs/).

Comment: this will wrap the responseText to dom tree and find body in it. and assing the content of body element to error text. good answer.

Comment: @Alien: It wraping an html string in `$()` will parse it into an HTML DOM/DOMFragment. This is basically all that happens if you use `dataType: 'html'` in your optsion hash to `$.ajax`. Then passing this new fragment as the context to to select the body from basically only grabs the body element...

Comment: I tried this already. For some reason errorText remains null :/ Both the one I use in my question and this one seem like they should work, but they don't.

Comment: @Darin Your code is the same as doing `var errorText = jqXHR.responseText;`

Comment: @Edgar Not true.  He's constructing a new DOM node, appending the responsetext into it (which creates additional nodes--see my answer), and then getting the HTML of it to strip off the wrapping `<div>` tags.  A fine solution, surely based off my discoveries below! :)

Comment: @Adam Terlson, my update was not based on your discoveries as I posted it 17 minutes ago whereas you answered 15 minutes ago. I've actually googled it.

Comment: @Darin, this still will not work.. It only excludes `html` and `body` tags. It will return all tags inside `head` for example as well.. **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/c7Sfs/1/)**

Comment: Here is a more accurate jsfiddle darin, notice that the contents of head are pulled. http://jsfiddle.net/c7Sfs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()`

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var myHtml = '<div id="blah">hello world</div>';
console.log($(myHtml).filter('#blah').html());
```

This will show "hello world" in the console. It's HTML stored in a variable. You apply the filter() from jquery to that variable (see above) and you can access your dom that way even though it's in a variable.

Comment: @AlexFord Please see the above example. You're not using it right.

Comment: I am using it exactly as you have it and it's not working in my instance because of what jQuery does to the HTML and BODY tags when wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html is valid xml you can do

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( jqXHR.responseText ),
    body = $( xmlDoc ).find('body')[0],
    bodystring = body.xml || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(body);
```

now `bodystring` holds the entire `<body>` tag (*as a string*) and you can use it to append it in the DOM with

```
$('#mainContent').html( bodystring );
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hYukn/